# Prevent EnumProperty updating constantly on panel hover / Change EnumProperty items if action triggered

Tags: python, add-on

What I want to achieve here is to begin with a login panel:

[image]

And after successful login there are more options on panel displayed:

[image]

During login there is an access token retrieved, which is used for calls to API (token authentication). What happens here is that projects are fetched when still there is no token (there is a failsafe `if no token -> return no projects` as seen below):

[image]

However if I run script again now (and there is a token that is not None), the projects list appears:

[image]

There is a shortcoming of this solution, that function is executed (with call to API) everytime I hover on panel element.
What happens after project selection is a call to API to fetch list of directories present in the chosen project.

What I would be glad if you guys helped me with:

(1) Display non-empty projects list (retrieve them from server) after I click `Login`

(2) Minimize amount of calls to API (on each hover on panel right now)

CODE:
https://pastebin.com/XMsRrbtu

Comment: Welcome to bse. Unfortunately can't test as have no server set up. Small thing re style, suggest adding  `wm = context.window_manager`.   Could try:  only register the projects enum on a successful login with items a snapshot of list at login. Shortfall will not show live changes on serverside.   Maybe add  a refresh button?. Been having a similar issue with enum listing active gvim servers.  Makes blender start to lag after a while. A method I was considering was stashing a snapshot, and only updating list on a time or tries basis.

Comment: I do not need to keep up with changes on server. The thing I need is to load projects list on log in, and update directories list each time project is chosen from dropdown. What I am asking is an advice how to solve it, and then to try to solve it myself. Do you think, @batFINGER, the solution could be registering on log in, unregister on log out (PropertyGroup with enum related stuff)? Tried to do it, did not work, but it could probably be my mistake.

Comment: Myself would  lean towards a collection of projects, each having a collection of folders, populate on login. If it is another window manager prop it will not be saved in file. To have enum UI, simply parse the collections.